# What this secret floor puzzle at the entrance activates?

Tags: the-witness

There is this secret floor puzzle next to flowers which has 4 possible exits:

[image: secret floor black dot puzzle next to flowers in The Witness game]

and it makes the sound on completion like it activated something, but nothing actually happens. Usually puzzles with multiple solutions has some meaning or used as switches. So what does this puzzle actually activates?

To clarify, I'm aware of the significance of the failing scenario, I'm asking about successful scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After half an hour's research, I assert that it doesn't activate anything. Completing it provides a +1 for your total puzzle count, which makes it obligatory if you want to achieve 100% completion (it's one of the 523 puzzles).

Well, it seems to me the primary value is deliberately failing it, as it activates (changes) nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of an environmental puzzle. But, it is tricky.

From https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witness/Town_Obelisk#Symbol_4

> The last tricky part comes from the fact that the floor puzzle turns blue when completed, and does not match the color of the flowers. In order to complete the environmental puzzle, you'll have to deliberately fail by bypassing the first black hexagon required to pass the puzzle. Failing the puzzle will turn the line yellow, and you'll now be able to trace a path between the flowers.